# Fetching data from 2 tables using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

I got this tables:"Study","Users","Subjects".

> "Study" includes:**(id, user_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "Users"], subject_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "Subjects"], grade, date)**
>
> "Users" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**
>
> "Subjects" includes:**(id, career_id, name, description, hours)**

I wanna get something like this at the end:

[image]

Dont know what to do at the crudmodel/controller files to get the usernames, subjects names :S

This is my codeigniter code (my view file):

```
                    <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>

<tbody>
    <?php

    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record->id."</td>
                      <td>".$record->user."</td>
                      <td>".$record->subject."</td>
                      <td>".$record->grade."</td>
                      <td>".$record->date."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/edit')."/$record->id'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDIT</button></a> |
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/delete')."/$record->id'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button></a>

                  </tr>";
        }

       }
    ?>

</tbody>
```

Here my controller file:

```
  class Home extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();

         $this->load->model("Crudmodel");

    }
    public function index(){

        $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();

        $this->load->view('home', $data);

    }
```

My crudmodel:

```
class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();

     $this->load->database();

    }

    public function getRecords(){

        $this->db->select()//DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO
                 ->from()
                 ->join();

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q -> num_rows() > 0){

            return $q->result();
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Mate, i gotta put all "usernames" inside the column User and all names of the subjects inside column Subject, what should i do?

Comment: With any complex query like this, you should start by writing a SQL query that returns the desired results. Once that is working, then you can write the function fairly easily.

Comment: @Programming_guy check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**In Controller**

```
public function index(){

    # get all data in Study table
    $selectStudys = $this->Crudmodel->selectStudys();

    foreach ($selectStudys as $key => $study) 
    {
        # get UserNames
        $user = $this->Crudmodel->getName($study['user_id']);

        #get Subject Names
        $subject = $this->Crudmodel->getSubName($study['subject_id']);


        #append both NEW VALUES to same array


        $data[$key]['user_id'] = $user[0]['username'];
        $data[$key]['subject_id'] = $subject[0]['name'];

    }

    # Early it was id, Now it has name
    /*
        Example
        ---------
         - Early in user_id 2
         - Now in user_id Mathamatics

    */

    // print_r($data); # check the output

    $data['records'] = $selectStudys;
    $this->load->view('home', $data);

}
```

**In Model**

```
function selectStudys()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM study");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function getName($name)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE id = $name ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function getSubName($subject)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM Subjects WHERE id = $subject ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: But, whatabout my index function pal?

Comment: what index function ??

Comment: public function index(){

        $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();

        $this->load->view('home', $data);

    }

Comment: above controller function goes inside that

Comment: only you have to comment `print_r($data);` and add `$this->load->view('home', $data);`

Comment: I do not get it mate, should i delete all my functions?

Comment: Can you show me where should i put your functions, excuse me..i am a little dizzy :S

Comment: now just copy paste mycode. controller function and model function as well

Comment: just change variable. and this is same as above question you have asked

Comment: Yeah, but i changed the varibles and the programis not working :/

Comment: cz answer based on above question

Comment: Okay, let me check this out dude:)

Comment: Yeah, i already changed variables from database Now i gonna paste your code and i will tell you. Stay sharp!

Comment: I think so, your code seems to be okay but i dont know whats going on in my code. I gonna give you the right answer!

Comment: Mate, it  is not working properlynow :/, take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233409/error-trying-to-fetch-data-from-2-tables-codeigniter/43234016#43234016